# How do I get rid of fleas on my rabbit?

Tags: rabbits, parasites

I have tried remedies I got from the internet but they do not work and she still has fleas. I do not know what else to do.

Comment: What remedies have you tried? Home-grown or commercial?

Comment: Related:  http://pets.stackexchange.com/a/1374/356

Answer (score 6):

Precious Tijesunimi has some organic remedies in their answer, if appropriate these should be seriously considered. I have also heard of other organic options.

For a non-organic solution, there are a few options that are sold for cats and dogs that can also be used on Rabbits.

***Use extreme caution when choosing one of these methods, some can be fatal to rabbits***

- Do not use flea collars on Rabbits [Blackwell's Five-Minute Veterinary Consult: Small Mammal edited by Barbara L. Oglesbee page 149](http://books.google.com/books?id=uEpNZaRn0egC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Blackwell%27s+Five-Minute+Veterinary+Consult&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hjNwUrXZLozxkQenyYGAAQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Blackwell%27s%20Five-Minute%20Veterinary%20Consult&f=false)
- Do not use products containing Fipronil (i.e. [Frontline](http://www.hartz.com/About_Hartzpet/Research_and_Innovation/EPA_evaluation_of_pet_spot-on_products.aspx)) on Rabbits.[The Merck/Merial Manual For Pet Health: Cynthia M. Kahn, Scott Line](http://books.google.com/books?id=eE2IvM10IX4C&pg=PA990&dq=rabbit+flea+treatment+toxic+Fipronil&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YzJwUp_eE4O0kQfhr4GoAg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=rabbit%20flea%20treatment%20toxic%20Fipronil&f=false)

Bunnies are different then dogs and cats and can have fatal results if the wrong product or dosage is used.  Always consult a vet who is a ***skilled rabbit care provider*** before making a decision.

We have 3 bunnies that go camping with us, often in locations where wild bunnies live.  Also we volunteer with and are aware of several organizations that take in abandoned and neglected bunnies.  As you can image, the risk of parasites in all of these situation is large and a non-organic solutions may be the best choice.

We use Revolution (Selamectin) which requires a prescription in the US and is relatively expensive. We are aware of hundreds of bunnies that this product has been used on, and are not aware of any adverse side effects related to the treatment.

Again, what ever solution you choose; talk to a vet who is familiar with rabbits and flea treatments.  Conduct your own research and carefully consider before making your own choice.

Answer (score 4):

Flea treatment for your rabbit

- Comb your rabbit regularly with a [flea comb](http://www.petsmart.com/product/index.jsp?productId=3706190).
- If your rabbit stays in the house then it is possible that your house might also be infested so also treat your house.
- Also, Fleas find the smell of vinegar very offensive and it also makes the environment very acidic for them so grooming your rabbit with vinegar mixed with water would also prevent fleas
- If your rabbit stays in a cage make sure the cage is cleaned (with hot water preferably) and regularly vacuum the surroundings of the cage.

In addition to vinegar, some other things that repel fleas are [Peppermint Oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppermint), [Cinnamon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon), [Lemon Grass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cymbopogon).

Also see [this article](http://video.about.com/cats/Make-a-Homemade-Flea-Trap.htm) for how to make a homemade flea trap.

Answer (score 4):

You will ideally want to use a product containing Selamectin (UK brand name Stronghold - manufactured by Pfizer ETA: Revolution as suggested by James appears to be the US brand name) or Imidaclopromide (UK brand name Advantage - manufactured by Bayer) as these are effective against a number of parasites including fleas.

Most over the counter "spot on" treatments contain relatively benign ingredients or Ivermectin (UK brand name Ivermec) which is very effective in treating mites and lice but not fleas (This could be why the treatments you used didn't work!).

Fipronil (UK brand name Frontline) is effective against fleas but carries a manufacturer's warning due to number of reports of adverse reactions in small or young rabbits so should be used with caution.

*Source - Textbook of Rabbit Medicine, Frances Harcourt-Brown, ISBN 0 7506 4002 2*

Answer (score 2):

Stop, go to a veterinarian. They will prescribe a medicine like [Revolution for cats](http://www.revolution.com.au/#/tab/revolution-for-cats).

**Do not attempt** to pick up flea control off-the-shelf at a local store; you will kill your rabbit. There are only 3-4 specific brands that do not harm rabbits and the dosage is crucial. Only a veterinarian trained for "exotic" animals such as rabbits can give you the proper dosage.