# What is the difference between shedding and molting in Rabbits?

Tags: rabbits, terminology, shedding, molting

I have heard that rabbits molt and shed, what is the difference?  Is there any special care required in either case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shedding](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shedding#English) and [Molting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moult) (*or moulting*) are very similar, both mean to lose all or part of a covering of hair or skin. For rabbits (and other mammals) shedding is generally considered less pronounced than molting.

Speaking from experience I can tell you that a pet rabbit will be shedding a small amount of hair on pretty much constant bases, just like you see some hair in the bottom of the drain every morning as strand of hair or two falls off your head, the same applies to rabbits (*and cats and dogs*)

Molting on the other hand is more definitive loss of fur, it can leave strange hair patterns and/or bald spots

[image]
[image]

You should be combing/brushing your rabbit [at least weekly](http://rabbit.org/faq-grooming/) you may need to do it daily during a molt.  Rabbits clean themselves like a cat, but [are physically incapable of vomiting](http://www.rabbit.org/fun/answer11.html) limiting the amount of fur available for them to ingest as well as keeping hay always available, are the two primary ways of preventing [wool block](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/692).  There are several variables and you may [notice 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=WAr9sRH0ctgC&pg=PA99&dq=rabbit+moulting&hl=en&sa=X&ei=K_iOVJ6PEMqdNu35gLAP&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=rabbit%20moulting&f=false) or [4 cycles](https://books.google.com/books?id=vjDCWH04NgIC&pg=PA38&dq=rabbit+moulting&hl=en&sa=X&ei=K_iOVJ6PEMqdNu35gLAP&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=rabbit%20moulting&f=false) per year.

In my experience fall and spring tend to be the most significant times for a heavy molt.

The spring starts the time of year that we anticipate taking our rabbits outdoors and begin [flea treatmenst](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/925) (*Revolution by prescription for puppies and kittens*) Going outside to brush your bunny can be a good choice.

You will often notice that the fur that is ready to come out is white in color, lightly grasping this fur and pulling softly, will help remove it. You don't want to grasp to hard, or pull to much you just want the fur that is ready to come out to to come loose.

There is a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajOHpOAnONc) that shows the general technique, a rubber brush like those made by 'Kong' is also a good tool.