# Can cat/dog fleas breed on rabbits?

Tags: rabbits

My rabbit recently got fleas and we have a lot of cat and dogs in my neighborhood. I’m really worried that they can breed on her. So can cat or dog fleas breed on rabbits?

Comment: Related post about [treating fleas on rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/925/how-do-i-get-rid-of-fleas-on-my-rabbit/1016#1016)

Comment: Take a look at this question:
https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7874/can-my-rabbit-get-fleas-from-a-cat-or-dog