# How do you socialize a bunny that has been locked in a cage for many years with very little socialization?

Tags: behavior, rabbits, socializing

My grandma has had an unwanted bunny for about 4 years now. He is very skittish and not friendly because he has never been socialized. I was wondering if there's still hope for him and if he can be socialized so he can be let out of his cage more often and actually be able to enjoy it.

Currently, my grandma says she only lets him out when she cleans his cage and she puts him into a hallway that is blocked off with a gate, so he can't get out. When he is put into the blocked off hallway, he often just sits in the corner regardless of whether anyone is in there with him or not. He also kicks a lot if you try to pick him up to be put back into his cage.

Is there anyway we can try to socialize him? Does anyone know any rescue organizations that may take him if we can't?

Comment: Yes he can be socialized, you should be getting one or more answer about technique in the next day or two.  As for the rescue where do you live? City(nearest large)/State/Country.

Comment: Don't expect him not to kick when you pick him up. Even fully socialized bunnies do that. And sitting in a corner seems pretty normal behaviour

Answer (score 3):

There is hope :)
Allow him to get use to the new place first, I would leave him be and give him a place to hide to feel comfortable. Do this for the first 2 days.

Day 3 and on - allow him to roam in the room his cage is, you may sit on the floor and let him come to you if he wants. Be very gentle and soft spoken, try giving him treats if he comes to you.

Never force anything and don't feel bad if he never wants to be picked up, rabbits are not a fan of heights.

I find with fearful rabbits using a towel or small blanket is best. Drop the towel completely on top of him and wrap him up starting with him bum/hind legs, you want to be able to control his kicking. Then wrap the rest of him, hold him close to your body and place him where you want.

Rabbits are prone to spinal injuries from flailing around or having a bad fall.

He needs to have exercise daily (if you're home let him out until you leave or go to bed) they need lots of space and environmental enrichment. Related questions [Can house rabbits have free access to the whole house all the time?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1320) [Will owls attack small dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8126) & [How accurate does the 30 day span when applying revolution flea treatment need to be?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8194)

Another thing I will recommend is to neuter, un-neutered rabbits will spray and develop some aggressive behaviors. It also prevents certain cancers.

SPCA will typically take rabbits or you can try finding a home online (through Craigslist type sites).