# How to harness train my rabbit?

Tags: rabbits, leash-training

I have 2 four month old rabbits. I bought a harness and leash for rabbits, because I wanted them to be able to run freely in the fields and the garden with me next to them, while not losing them. I have tried to put the harness on and walk them.

Lilly tries to get away from me each time, because she sees me running after her, which makes her even more scared, and she leaps away and tries to hide.

Midnight is much worse. He runs around, super fast, in a circle and jumps and freaks out, and I am scared he and Lilly will hurt themselves or even kill themselves trying to get away!

I only want to help them, but I am scared for them. I have stopped trying for awhile, but am considering trying again in a few days. Can you give me  any tips on harness training a rabbit?

Comment: Possibly of interest [What causes rabbits to spontaneously change gender?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11064)

Answer (score 3):

First Harness training a Rabbit is pretty easy.  See our related question [How to leash train a rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/677) for all the how to.

Second and **Most Important** I have a couple of big concerns about your plan and expectations.

1. When domestic rabbits are outside, they don't run freely.  They are very territorial, and slow to advance.  If you set a domestic rabbit down in the middle of a field they will go out a 10 - 50 feet (1 - 15 meters) and comeback.  It is not at all like taking a dog for walk. They prefer to lay in the shade or undercover and eat grass.
2. Fleas and parasites are big issue when you take your rabbit outside.  See our related questions [How do I get rid of fleas on my rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/925) & [How accurate does the 30 day span when applying revolution flea treatment need to be?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8194) Revolution is the drug you should use it requires prescription and it is fairly expensive.

I suspect most of the issues you describe with getting the harness on are addressed in this quote from my answer at [How to leash train a rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/677)

> The largest hurdle is getting the harness securely without upsetting your bunny. You have to fasten under their neck, and this is a bunny's least favorite place to be handled. Once it is on, you're fine. Some may try to chew at it, but most will ignore it once it is in place

Answer (score 0):

the way I did it for my two boys is I left the harnesses on for a long period of time for them to get used to the feel of one and then throughout this time I got them habituated to humans being around them, this helps with their jumpiness as well. 
Once they had gotten used to humans, I put their leads onto the harness and took one at a time outside in my arms, I then sat down with the rabbit and let them explore with me sitting down as they then see you as less of a threat.
they are now both walkable with thumper being able to walk alongside you, as long as you are holding a treat!!