# My pet rat keeps hurting herself and I don't know what to do

Tags: behavior, injury, skin-condition, rat

So I've had my pet rat for 2 months now and when we first got her she had a tiny scab on the back of her neck. It wasn't a big deal, but now she has a huge scab that I constantly see her biting and scratching at, along with 2 or 3 other scabs that she's constantly picking at. She's in a cage by herself, so I know it's her doing it and I'm really worried that one of the cuts will get infected.

Comment: You probably need to visit your vet.  It could be allergies and/or fleas. Use caution with self treatment as an example [some flea treatments ok for dogs can be fatal to rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/925/how-do-i-get-rid-of-fleas-on-my-rabbit/1016#1016)

Comment: I agree that you should let a vet have a look at her. It could be a parasite, an allergy, dry skin or something completely different that we won't be able to diagnose in this forum.

Comment: I would also bring the rat to the vet. But, for the immediate problem, they also make Elizabethan collars aka cones of shame for rats.

Answer (score 2):

She probably has fleas or a skin problem bothering her, I would 100% bring her to the vet and get that checked out.