# Cat keeps getting cuts on his face!

Tags: cats, injury, containment

My cat, named Butterscotch, keeps cutting open his face. I'm not really sure how he is doing this, because I have checked everywhere and there is nothing that could cut his face open! I took him to the vet and the vet said that it wasn't a problem and that he just got cut. After he did it a few more times, we took him back. Still, the vet said it was nothing.

Is there something I can do to:

- heal the cut?
- stop it from happening?

I think I found the culprit. Found out my cat could jump on top of my shower doors. There was a conch shell on the cabinet to get up there. Is it possible this would scratch him? He bled quite a bit but I didn't see any blood on the conch shell.

Comment: Outside of following him around for a day or two and trying to figure out what he is doing to himself, I have no suggestions. Is he an indoor-only or outdoor cat? Is he interacting with other cats?  Have you trimmed his claws to make sure he isn't snagging himself when scratching asn itch?

Comment: Unfortunately, he was declawed before I found out you shouldn't declaw cats. He is indoor only. There are no other cats or animals in the house.

Comment: I don't know about the conch shell, but is there a metal frame around the shower doors? They often have rough/sharp/pointy spots.

Comment: Did you look under the bed?  Cats an Rabbits will occasionally find their way into the box springs of a mattress.

Comment: are his back feet declawed too? He might be scratching himself with his back toes. You said he's declawed but it's usually only common practice to declaw the front paws, but cats itch their chins/faces with their back feet usually...

Comment: My cat scratches a scar on his cheek.. It's been a year with an e cone & every time I take it off, he scratches it again... I've tried everything I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several camera options that can help you find the cause.

Set up a camera (*preferably with motion activation*) in the place(s) you think is the most likely cause.  Comparing new injuries with the video should be very helpful in identifying the cause.

There are also cat mounted cameras but I am [not a fan of collars on cats.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/should-i-put-a-collar-on-my-indoor-cat/11896#11896)

Comment: Worth a shot. I happen to have some cameras that I could set up.