# Besides collar where else can I put name tag on my cat?

Tags: cats, gps

One of my kitten is leaving me. I want to put either a name tag or a GPS tracker.

However, I fear that a collar may get him "stuck" on some places or even killing him.

I've heard that there is a harness or something. Would that work? Would that be better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your cat is wandering and you don't want it to, **keep it inside.** House cats live longer, healthier lives, and are perfectly happy living safely in their homes as long as they have sufficient stimulation.

If you are not willing to keep your cat inside, put a tag on a **cat-safe breakaway collar**. Cats are naturally going to get into tight areas, and a tag hanging from a non-breakaway collar will result in a trapped, and possibly dead, cat. Collars approved for cats are made with clips that will pull apart with sufficient force, allowing the cat to pull itself free easily if the collar or tag become stuck somewhere. The cat will no longer have an ID tag at this point, so an **implanted ID chip** is a highly recommended backup to identify the pet if picked up by another individual or animal control.

**Do not turn your cat loose while wearing a harness.** Ever. The same hazards to a caught collar will apply to a caught harness, and while cats can often figure out how to twist their way out of a harness, the cat may be stuck in a position where it is unable to do so, or may not be able to figure it out. **A harness is meant for supervised time on a leash only**; a cat should never wear it while not being supervised. It is designed to be difficult to escape from because it is designed to keep the cat under control while leashed.

Comment: Related post [Should I put a collar on my indoor cat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/should-i-put-a-collar-on-my-indoor-cat)

Comment: Cat-safe collars are not 100% safe for the car. Look at this story for example. http://www.catforum.com/forum/36-cat-chat/148789-breakaway-safe-cat-collar-didnt-come-off.html#/topics/148789 The safest is not to use any collar but just an implanted ID chip. Any vet can read it. If you are scared of other people taking your cat, letting your cat outside is maybe not for you (any reasonable person can see if a cat is in a good, clean and healthy shape and infer that is has an owner. But you can never protect your cat of crazy people and accidents).

Answer (score 2):

Get a microchip.  They are very inexpensive at Petco or other shot clinics.

Breakaway collars are great, but they can get caught on things kitty walks past and end up on the floor or in a bush outside.  Cats like to mark objects with their cheek, so it happens.

I suggest a harness, then you can take your cat for a walk.  Less complicated is better, as cats often hate clothing and wearing stuff.