# What kind of information collar fits for a rabbit?

Tags: rabbits, outdoor, identification, collar

My male rabbit all second day escapes the backyard. His wife stays in the garden and he comes back for her all the time. He goes for adventure to the neighbors' gardens and the nearby park. Our direct neighbors know him and let him go. But I am worried about "strangers" who see him and think he is lost. Maybe they'll catch him to give him a new home. Especially if they see him more than once.

(The backyard is Fort Knox, but he disappears... if someone knows a rabbit forensic unit, they are welcome!)

He has a chip, but I wish to add more direct information (phone number or address or such) to inform people he has a home.

EDIT: It does not have to be on the neck. Maybe there is another position with less risk of strangulation?

What kind of collar/belt/anything is mostly safe for him to transport such information?

Comment: Why don't you install (temporarily) a camera, to understand how does your rabbit escape? Gradually, you will get to the point where you have all escape paths closed.

Comment: @virolino Yes this idea is in my mind too. But the garden is tricky to see as whole so I have to wait some times him escaping. I want to follow two was. In long I want to close all ways.

Comment: You need to notice that you only need to monitor the "fences". Install the camera to "see" along a fence. See if you get lucky. Move the camera along another fence. Repeat. Another fence. Repeat. It will be slower, but still doable. It will be faster if you have several cameras. It is unlikely that the rabbit started a hole in the middle of the garden, to exit somewhere outside your property. The analysis of the recordings will give you the info you need. There is software to detect movement in the video, so you do not need to watch hundreds of hours of still garden.

Comment: There might be cameras with motion detection, so they will record only when something changes in the image.

Comment: After 4 month of magic rabbit disappearance I spotted him by chance while he left the garden: he jumped around 50 cm high through a hole in the fence. The hole is maximum 15cm in diameter and has nothing to jump up, sit and jump down again. Looked like the tiger-through-the-ring in circus. I locked this too and since then he did not disappeare anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing with a collar is that it breaks off if your rabbit gets stuck. You can ask your vet or pet shop about what type they recommend as it might differ with the weight of your rabbit.

The information to put on the collar is your phone number and, if you are comfortable with it, the street name and house number.

In addition you can hang a sign on the collar saying "If you find me close to (street name) I am not lost", or something similar.

Be sure to keep a current picture of your rabbit in case it really gets lost so you can put up missing posters close to where you live.

Answer (score -3):

I have found a discription how to make a safe cat collar. Following the discription it will break by pull of approx. 1kg and should last between 4 and 6 weeks.

The collar is simple a stripe of very stable paper called "Chromolux". Like all paper the information could be written on it. In the discription of Chromolux I read the paper is painted on one side with lacquer. I assume this cause a water resistance.

Combined with a snap or simple sticky tape it could be formed to a collar. The collar could be made more visible with reflecting stickers or more personal with rhinestones or whatever one imagines.

Now I am waiting for my order and will report the test (not on the living animal) about the stability here later.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but this is a **REALLY BAD IDEA**.  Cats and Rabbits have very different bone strength.  Cats are carnivores! When a cat and a rabbit fight in the wild, the cat breaks the neck of the rabbit.  A rabbit never breaks the neck of the cat.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Do you think a neck of a rabbit could not stand 1kg pressure? All other collars I find need more power to break. My worries about the differences between cat and rabbit cause me to ask this question. If not I simple had bought a cats collar.

Comment: 1kg is a lot for a rabbit that weighs maybe 3kg.  Also rabbits run fast, if it catches on something while he is running, the speed combined with the 1kg could make the force on the rabbit much greater. Maybe research 'foot-pound per second' to help understand how the faster speed mean more energy.  I don't know that your solution is bad, but I have concerns.

Comment: @JamesJenkins the break point of the paper collar will be lower as thinner the paper will be cut. Maybe there is a measure where it is thin enought to break but big enought to not cut in the skin and write on it. If I have answer in this [question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26880/if-the-rabbit-has-a-collar-at-which-weight-need-the-collar-to-break-so-the-rabb) I will do further research.

Comment: If the paper rolls up it might get harder to break.  sometimes it can twist like a rope, and get much stronger.

Comment: @JamesJenkins is there an alternative position/ material?

Comment: Collars for rabbits have issues besides breaking necks, the rabbits head is smaller than their neck. When [attaching a rabbit to a leash I use a harness](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/735/13) but I am not sure this is a good solution for you.  I have never seen a break away harness.