# Can I leash my rabbit

Tags: rabbits

I have brought rabbit for my home and she is of approx 2.5 months. My query is Can I put leash on her as she is very playfull.

I am trying to put her leash as attached image so kindly help me on the same.[image: How I apply leash on my bunny]

Comment: related: [How to leash train a rabbit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/677/how-to-leash-train-a-rabbit) (Also information about how to choose the right harness)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can put a leash on a bunny.

But please keep these important things in mind!

**Never leash your bunny with a collar!**

Not only will this not contain your bunny when it jumps away suddenly, but the collar can harm your pet if sudden force is applied. If you wish to leash your bunny please use a bunny harness. The harness makes sure your bunny cannot wriggle out, and it distributes the force of pulls onto the whole bunny.

**Make sure your bunny is OK with being leashed.**

There are pets that simply do not tolerate a harness or leash. Unlike dogs training is not always successful. Make sure your bunny is OK with the harness before going outside. Maybe read this question: [How to harness train my rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/13795/how-to-harness-train-my-rabbit)

**Never tie the leash to anything!**
Keep the leash in your hand at all times to be able to react to sudden movements. Rabbits are animals of prey, and they can panic in certain situations.

I think this [article](https://bunnyapproved.com/rabbits-on-a-leash-what-you-need-to-know/) could be very helpful to you. It describes how a harness and leash should be and how to use them. Generally read up on the topic before going outside with your bunny. I would like to note here that a bunny will not walk with you like a dog. A leash can be helpful when you are in an unfenced area or meadow.

Comment: Can I keep collar on her withour harness ?

Comment: No, you need a harness. Collar is dangerous! Your rabbit can escape or die.

Comment: I will not tie her just a neck collar with small tinkle if its safe ...

Comment: it is not safe for a rabbit to wear a collar. Even without leash. The risk to get trapped is to high. Rabbits would struggle and break their own neck, if the collar would get stucked somewhere. You need a special collar, which breaks in this case. See the linked question in the next comment

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26880/if-a-rabbit-has-a-collar-at-what-weight-should-the-collar-break-so-the-rabbit-w/26890?r=SearchResults#26890