# Can I keep thread and bell around rabbits neck

Tags: rabbits

I have 1 year old female rabbit it roams freely in my home and sometime it is not possible to find him. So can I tie a bell on his neck with cotton thread so I can be aware of his position based on bell sound. He is Albino newzealand rabbit.

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26858/what-kind-of-information-collar-fits-for-a-rabbit

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26880/if-a-rabbit-has-a-collar-at-what-weight-should-the-collar-break-so-the-rabbit-w?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No

Long answer: Rabbits shape of head enables them to slip out from a collar. And additional rabbits caught by accident because the collar linked to something like a hook or stick, would struggle hard to get free and even break their own bones or neck.

IF you want to take the risk, you could try a thin paper collar. But also this could get unintentional strong by winding itself up.

So a rabbit should not wear any collar or harness when unsupervised.